# German dataset for training text classifier

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am looking for an annotated dataset in German similar to the well-known English IMDB movie review dataset ([here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-imdb-movie-reviews)).
The background is that I would like to categorize German texts into multiple categories (starting with positive sentiment / negative / neutral).
I have not found German word embeddings pre-trained with sentiment analysis, neither have I found a suitable dataset to train my own word embeddings with.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

not exactly what you are looking for, but here you can find a german dataset for text classification:
https://tblock.github.io/10kGNAD/

https://ofai.github.io/million-post-corpus/

Answer (score 0):

Datasets for Natural Language Processing tasks (such as Sentiment Analysis) are called **Corpus**.

*Why are they important?*

- They provide the model with the *context* **features** (the words used for classifying).

  - If you are using some Embeddings, the corpus provides the means to obtain the vectors used to determine the model.

*What to take in account when chosing a Corpus?* Meditate on the following questions:

- Is the corpus I'm selecting providing the important features for my model?
- Is my context well represented by the corpus? Is it about the same thing or too generic?

So, instead of just checking for any corpus similar to IMDB, first check if there's an annotated corpus for your problem context in your language. If there's one, good. Else, build yours, its not too hard to get a minimum functional corpus that works better than a too generic corpus - if you decide to follow this path, check on Doccano, an opensource annotation tool: https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano.

**A note of caution**: Sentiment Analysis may seem to do well with any generic corpus, however keep in mind that every context has its special jargons that can represent good or bad things.